# TypeError: Cannot read property 'classify' of undefined (save ml5.js model )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror, ml5.js

I am using an ml5.js setup in my React app where I click on a button to train a model and then I click on another button to make predictions. The Test button works on the first time but it throws an error on the second time:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'classify' of undefined
```

I believe this is because once I run the prediction part, the model gets deleted? Because the classifier is now undefined. How can I modify it such that I can repeatedly click on the Test button and obtain new predictions each time.

I tried the save() function but apparently it only downloads the model and not save it for the app.

```
export const Video: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    const [prediction, setPrediction] = useState<string>();

    let capture: p5Types.Element;
    let classifier: any;
    const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
        capture = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
        const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
        classifier = featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
    }

    const draw = (p5: p5Types) => {
    }
    function gotResult() {
        classifier.classify(capture, (err: any, result: any) => {
            setPrediction(result[0].label);
        });
    }

    function train() {
        classifier.train((lossValue: any) => {
            console.log('Loss is', lossValue);
        });
        //classifier.save();
    }



    return (<div><Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} className="sketch" />
        <div className="button">
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => classifier.addImage('first')}>First</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => classifier.addImage('second')}>Second</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="secondbutton">
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => train()}>Train!</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => gotResult()}>Test!</Button>
            <br />
            <span>Prediction: {prediction}</span>
        </div>
    </div>)
        ;
};
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-solomon-zb34l?file=/src/Component.tsx

Updated code:

```
export const VideoComponent: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    const [prediction, setPrediction] = useState<string>();
    const [confidence, setConfidence] = useState<string>();
    const [trainingComplete, setTrainingComplete] = useState<boolean>();
    const captureRef = useRef<p5Types.Element>();
const classifierRef = useRef<any>();

    const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {

        const capture = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
    const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor("MobileNet", modelReady);
    captureRef.current = capture;
    classifierRef.current = featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
    }

    const draw = (p5: p5Types) => {
    }


    function gotResult() {
        console.log('classifier in results', classifierRef.current);
        classifierRef.current.classify(captureRef.current, (err: any, result: any) => {
            setPrediction(result[0].label);
            setConfidence(result[0].confidence);

        });
    }

    function train() {
        console.log('classifier in train', classifierRef.current);
        classifierRef.current?.classify.train((lossValue: any) => {
            console.log('Loss is', lossValue);
            if (lossValue == null) {
                //setTrainingComplete(true);
                console.log('training complete')
            }
        });
    }



    return (
    <div>
        <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} className="sketch" />
        <div className="button">
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => { classifierRef.current?.classifier.addImage('first'); console.log('image added') }}>First</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => { classifierRef.current?.classifier.addImage('second'); console.log('image added') }}>Second</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="secondbutton">
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => train()}>Train!</Button>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => gotResult()}>Test!</Button>
            <br />
            {trainingComplete && (<span>Training Complete!</span>)}<br />
            <span>Prediction: {prediction}</span><br />
        </div>
    </div>)
        ;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the two `let` variables, `capture` and `classifier`, which you are using to store stateful data.

```
let capture: p5Types.Element;
let classifier: any;
const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
    capture = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
    const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
    classifier = featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
}
```

These variables get re-created on every re-render.  If you want to have instance variables which persist across re-renders then you need to use `useState` or `useRef`.  Since these two variables come from the `p5` package and might be modified by other functions I think `useRef` is probably what you want here.  You can [read more about `useRef` in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

You need to add some extra conditionally checks in your code since `captureRef.current` could be either an `Element` or `undefined`, so you need to make sure that you have an `Element` before using it.  For `classifier` you can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this: `classifierRef.current?.classify()`.

```
const captureRef = useRef<p5Types.Element>();
const classifierRef = useRef<any>();

const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
    // I'm assigning to a variable before assigning to the ref
    // so that we know that it is always defined inside this function
    const capture = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
    const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor("MobileNet", modelReady);
    captureRef.current = capture;
    classifierRef.current = featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
    console.log("start", classifierRef.current);
};
```

You should try to find or create an actual type for `classifier` instead of `any`.  It looks like [there is no types package for `ml5`](https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-library/issues/253), but [someone created a draft](https://gist.github.com/dikarel/38a12ce263199a41ad67c15eac7f4b45).

Comment: You access `classifierRef.current?` because it's a ref.

Comment: Edited according to your suggestion but then it gives me ```VideoComponent.tsx:84 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addImage' of undefined``` the very first time I click on the "first" button. Were you able to correctly run and test in the sandbox? Added the updated code in the qs

Comment: No I got all sorts of errors.  Let me look at it again.

Comment: I think there's an error being thrown while creating the model so that it never gets created.  I'm seeing errors in the log like "DOMException: Permission denied` and "Uncaught Error: Cannot add node 1 because a node with that id is already in the Store."

Comment: Are you sure you're on the correct link and have a stable net? https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-solomon-zb34l?file=/src/Component.tsx Because I am not using any ids and store values